# Django generate csv file on view and download

Tags: python, django, csv

I have this code:

```
    with open('stockitems_misuper.csv', 'wb') as myfile:
        wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
        wr.writerows(file_rows)

    response = HttpResponse(myfile, content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=stockitems_misuper.csv'
    return response
```

I get the error:

> I/O operation on closed file

How can I send the created csv file to the front end?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

you're passing the handle of the file being written (and not sure of your indentation, you could just be outside the `with` block.

Just reopen it in read mode.

```
with open('stockitems_misuper.csv', 'w', newline="") as myfile:  # python 2: open('stockitems_misuper.csv', 'wb')
    wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    wr.writerows(file_rows)

with open('stockitems_misuper.csv') as myfile:
    response = HttpResponse(myfile, content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=stockitems_misuper.csv'
    return response
```

or better: write to a `io.StringIO()` instance, and pass that, avoiding to create the file.

```
import io,csv

buffer = io.StringIO()  # python 2 needs io.BytesIO() instead
wr = csv.writer(buffer, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
wr.writerows(file_rows)

buffer.seek(0)
response = HttpResponse(buffer, content_type='text/csv')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=stockitems_misuper.csv'

return response
```

Comment: I had to change the import to `from io import BytesIO as StringIO` and `buffer = StringIO()` to make this work, but otherwise great solution!

Comment: that's because you're using Python 2 (in your example you're using "wb" to create the csv file so it has to be python 2, edited)

Comment: wouldn't the buffer hold the complete file_rows within memory and therefore eliminate the advantages of a streaming http response?

Comment: that could probably be done, with a custom object having a "read" method, which consumes data from `file_rows` when needed. More complex. If the file is small, not worth it.

Comment: Will this be feasible for very large CSV files? If not then how can I implement it.